How to Use GoRouter for Dynamic Webpage Building?
I'm new to Flutter, but I'm exploring its features. I'm attempting to use GoRouter to build pages dynamically. For example, if I have a URL, "mydomain.com/", I could specify a parameter like "mydomain.com/thing", and that parameter will change the page in some way, like a title.
The end goal is to have that parameter be an ID that correlates to a primary key in my database in which I will load the rest of the page based on the results of the query.
Here's the code I have for reference:
class WebApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            const String title = 'Home';
            return const MyHomePage(title: title);
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/:input',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            final String title = state.pathParameters['input'] ?? 'Home';
            return MyHomePage(title: title);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
      title: 'Flutter Dynamic Title',
    );
  }
}

This will always generate a page with 'Home' as the title even if I input a path parameter. How can I make the path parameter properly impact the page?
For extra context, here's MyHomePage:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

I've tried using the base routes module, but then switched over to GoRouter hoping that would work. I've tried using multiple different routes with hardcoded titles that would generate if I selected those routes, but that didn't work. I then found the GoRouter's 'state.pathParameters' object that I hoped would solve my problems, but it didn't. Now, I'm just confused...

I usually use the extra as params. See example below.
Taking this part from your provided code.
GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        const String title = 'Home';
        return const MyHomePage(title: title);
      },
    ),

if you want to pass the parameter title you can use the extra found in the GoRouter state object. You can use custom classes to pass multiple parameters also.
//your custom class    
class MyHomePageParams {
      MyHomePageParams({required this.title});
      final String title;
    }

GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      final params = state.extra as MyHomePageParams
        const String title = params.title;
        return const MyHomePage(title: title);
      },
    ),

Then to navigate to that route simply:
context.push('/',extra:MyHomePageParams(title:'home'));

